# How to keep advanced search in magento Home Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, magento-community

I wish to keep an advanced search in my store. First a dropdown with two values should be listed like `vehicle` and `dimension`. The next `details` regarding either the `vehicle` or the `dimension` should be displayed only when the user select the value ( `vehicle` `dimension` ). If the user select the `vehicle` option then the associated dropdowns like `brand` & `color` should be shown . Can this be done in magento?

Answer (score 0):

First create `form.phtml` file at location `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalogsearch/advanced/home/`

after add bellow code in file `form.phtml`

```
<?php $maxQueryLength= $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getMaxQueryLength();?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Catalog Advanced Search') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result') ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset advanced-search">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Search Settings') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list" id="advanced-search-list">
            <?php foreach ($this->getSearchableAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
            <?php $_code = $_attribute->getAttributeCode() ?>
            <li>
                <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute) ?></label>
                <?php switch($this->getAttributeInputType($_attribute)):
                    case 'number': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $_code ?>[from]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'from')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>" class="input-text validate-number" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $_code ?>[to]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'to')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_to" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>" class="input-text validate-number" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'price': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <input name="<?php echo $_code ?>[from]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'from')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text validate-number" type="text" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <input name="<?php echo $_code ?>[to]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'to')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_to" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text validate-number" type="text" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <small>(<?php echo $this->getCurrency($_attribute); ?>)</small>
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'select': ?>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getAttributeSelectElement($_attribute) ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'yesno': ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAttributeYesNoElement($_attribute) ?>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'date': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <?php echo $this->getDateInput($_attribute, 'from') ?>
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <?php echo $this->getDateInput($_attribute, 'to') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    default: ?>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $_code ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text <?php echo $this->getAttributeValidationClass($_attribute) ?>" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php endswitch; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('advanced-search-list')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Now call this phtml file in admin side homepage content from `CMS->Pages`

```
{{block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/home/form.phtml"}}
```

**OR**

add bellow code in **header.phtml** file

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/home/form.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I tried your code. Thank you. But I dont need a form. I just need a dropdown with two options (vehicle, dimension).  Then When I select vehicle, two dropdown for brand & color should get displayed for us to choose.